How do I fix this Mapbox error always occurring when I run my React Native project?
I keep getting this error when I try using mapbox on react native cli, how doni fix it?
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/images/RNMBXImagesManager.kt:212:5 'addView' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/images/RNMBXImagesManager.kt:227:5 'removeView' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/images/RNMBXImagesManager.kt:236:5 'removeAllViews' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:13:5 'getChildAt' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:17:5 'getChildCount' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:21:5 'addView' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/java/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/components/styles/sources/RNMBXTileSourceManager.kt:25:5 'removeViewAt' overrides nothing
e: file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/startup-folder/Last-Mile-delivery-Software/driver-mobile-app/node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/android/src/main/rn-compat/rn75/com/rnmapbox/rnmbx/rncompat/ResourceDrawableIdHelper.kt:5:37 Unresolved reference: Companion
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rnmapbox_maps:compileDebugKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3m 46s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
